# filebeat set ouput to kafka, meet "dropping invalid message",what's wrong with it

Tags: apache-kafka, filebeat

I want to monitor the content of the log file and push it to Kafka，

My log message like this,

```
2020-12-05 15:00:57|HttpImp.cpp:99:doHttpResp|3174483435377658880|method|POST|moduleName|staff|funcName|queryCmuEmployee|channelCode|23004023|body|160|costime|18|httpcode|200|rspMessage|{"code":0,"message":"success","data":{"communityName":"\u4e0a\u6d77\u5e02\u6d3e\u514b\u516c\u9986","organizations":[{"parentOrganizationNames":[],"organizationID":"0dd4d2931f97c6de97610","organizationName":"\u6d\u6dfb\u52a0\u6295\u8bc9\u88ab\u63d0\u9192\u4eba","userType":31,"info":{},"parentOrganizationIDs":[]},{"communityID":"9a47b14dec84e998cd3b9d2b074d543b","communityName":"\u4e0a\u6d77\u5e02\u6d3e\u514b\u516c\u9986","userType":31,"info":{"nameInCmu":"\u738b\u516d","createTime":"2019-09-27 17:34:22","operatorName":"\u738b\u8d1d","staffIndexv":45}}],"communityID":"9a47b14dec84e998cd3b9d2b074d543b"}}
```

And I config the filebeat.yml as follows,

input,

```
 21 - type: log
 22 
 23   # Change to true to enable this input configuration.
 24   enabled: true
 25 
 26   # Paths that should be crawled and fetched. Glob based paths.
 27   paths:
 28 #    - /var/log/*.log
 29     - /usr/local/app/tars/app_log/midplatform/GateSvrReceiver/midplatform.GateSvrReceiver_access*.log
 30     #- c:\programdata\elasticsearch\logs\*
```

ouput,

```
173 # ================================== Outputs ===================================
174 
175 # Configure what output to use when sending the data collected by the beat.
176 
177 # ---------------------------- Kafka Output ----------------------------
178 output.kafka:
179   hosts: ["172.16.16.30:9092"]
180   topic: 'log_gatesvrreceiver'
181
```

then, i meet the error,

```
2020-12-05T15:04:13.552+0800    ERROR   [kafka] kafka/client.go:256     Kafka (topic=log_gatesvrreceiver): dropping invalid message
2020-12-05T15:04:13.552+0800    ERROR   [kafka] kafka/client.go:256     Kafka (topic=log_gatesvrreceiver): dropping invalid message
2020-12-05T15:04:13.552+0800    ERROR   [kafka] kafka/client.go:256     Kafka
```

what's the problem?